# How to query unique outlook meeting id in powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook

I have below powershell code that displays all my outlook meetings. For recurring series, i need to identify a unique meeting ID for each occurrence. All the fields (GlobalAppointmentID, entryid,ConversationIndex) i tried are giving me the same ID. What field should i use to differentiate each occurrence.

```
Function Get-OutlookCalendar {
    param ( [DateTime] $rangeStart = [DateTime]::Now.AddDays(-2)
      , [DateTime] $rangeEnd   = [DateTime]::Now.AddDays(+1)) 

    $outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
    $session = $outlook.Session
    $session.Logon()
    $olFolderCalendar = 9
    $apptItems = $session.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderCalendar).Items
    $apptItems.Sort("[Start]")
    $apptItems.IncludeRecurrences = $true
    $range = "[End] >= '{0}' AND [Start] <= '{1}'" -f $rangeStart.ToString("g"), $rangeEnd.ToString("g")
    $myObject = New-Object System.Object
    $result=@()
    foreach($appt in $apptItems.Restrict($range)) { 
       $result+=$appt
    }
    return $result
} 

Get-OutlookCalendar | %{
    if($_.subject -like 'match.com test meeting'){
        $_
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't know the answer to your question yet, but please stop making an array and appending to it to just return it. It's unnecessary and slow. Simply remove the result variable and return and just have it like this `foreach($appt in $apptItems.Restrict($range)){$appt}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented, there is absolutely no need to "new" up an array `$result = @()`, destroy and rebuild it every iteration `$result += $appt`, just to output it `return $result`.

As far as differentiating the recurring meetings from each other, the only consistent way I found to do that is by using one of the date properties. Any of the start properties are candidates and the ticks subproperty is perfect.

**Updated function**

```
Function Get-OutlookCalendar {
    param ( [DateTime] $rangeStart = [DateTime]::Now.AddDays(-2),
      [DateTime] $rangeEnd   = [DateTime]::Now.AddDays(+30)
      ) 

    $outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
    $session = $outlook.Session
    $session.Logon()
    $olFolderCalendar = 9
    $apptItems = $session.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderCalendar).Items
    $apptItems.Sort("[Start]")
    $apptItems.IncludeRecurrences = $true
    $range = "[End] >= '{0}' AND [Start] <= '{1}'" -f $rangeStart.ToString("g"), $rangeEnd.ToString("g")
    foreach($appt in $apptItems.Restrict($range)) { 
        $appt
    }
}
```

**Looking at the start properties.**

```
$entries = Get-OutlookCalendar

$entries | where {$_.subject -like 'test'} | foreach {
    $_ | Get-Member -Name start* | where name -notmatch 'timezone'
}

Name     MemberType Definition                   
----     ---------- ----------                   
Start    Property   Date Start () {get} {set}    
StartUTC Property   Date StartUTC () {get} {set} 
Start    Property   Date Start () {get} {set}    
StartUTC Property   Date StartUTC () {get} {set} 

$entries | where {$_.subject -like 'test'} | foreach {
    $_.start
}

Wednesday, September 23, 2020 8:00:00 AM
Thursday, September 24, 2020 8:00:00 AM
Friday, September 25, 2020 8:00:00 AM
```

**And the recommended ticks subproperty**

```
$entries | where {$_.subject -like 'test'} | foreach {
    $_.start.ticks
}

637364448000000000
637365312000000000
637366176000000000
```